# How to fix: "EPROTO" Error after upgrading Node's version

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, request

The following code works on Node's `v10.15.3` version:

```
const { post } = require('request');

post({
  url: 'https://cidadao.sinesp.gov.br/sinesp-cidadao/mobile/consultar-placa/v4',
  body: '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n<v:Envelope xmlns:v=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n  <v:Header>\n    <b>LGE Nexus 5</b>\n    <c>ANDROID</c>\n    <d>v4</d>\n    <e>4.3.2</e>\n    <f>98.193.54.223</f>\n    <g>514650d8dba4784ed08b5a029583576361a50bc5</g>\n    <h>-3272.3179572637086</h>\n    <i>940.839492700698</i>\n    <j/>\n    <k/>\n    <l>2019-05-24 10:24:35</l>\n    <m>8797e74f0d6eb7b1ff3dc114d4aa12d3</m>\n  </v:Header>\n  <v:Body xmlns:n0=\"http://soap.ws.placa.service.sinesp.serpro.gov.br/\">\n    <n0:getStatus>\n      <a>LSU3J43</a>\n    </n0:getStatus>\n  </v:Body>\n</v:Envelope>',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'User-Agent': 'SinespCidadao / 3.0.2.1 CFNetwork / 758.2.8 Darwin / 15.0.0',
    Host: 'cidadao.sinesp.gov.br'
  },
}, (err, httpResponse, body) => {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(httpResponse));
});
```

But after upgrading to `v12.2.0` or above I got the following error:

> ```
> Error: write EPROTO 17432:error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\statem\statem_lib.c:1922:
>
>     at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:83:16) {
>   errno: 'EPROTO',
>   code: 'EPROTO',
>   syscall: 'write'
> }
> ```

How can I fix it?

Comment: The certificate of website `cidadao.sinesp.gov.br` has already been expired since May 2018.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

As the same code works on Node.js `v10.15.3`, but not work on `v12.2.0`, and the error message indicates "unsupported protocol", the most possible root cause of this issue is: the minimal supported TLS version in Node.js 10 is `TLSv1.0`, but since `v11.4.0`, it is raised to `TLSv1.2` ([tls.DEFAULT_MIN_VERSION](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_default_min_version)). I suspect the certificate of `cidadao.sinesp.gov.br` is signed with TLSv1.0, which works on Node.js `v10.15.3`, but not on `v12.2.0`.

To make Node.js accept `TLSv1.0`, you can lauch Node.js process with `--tls-min-v1.0` option.

I made an experiment and it works well:

[image]

BTW, the certificate of `cidadao.sinesp.gov.br` is invalid now. It has been expired since May 2018 -- as the OP mentioned, the request should be sent from Brazil (or through proxy node in Brazil).

Comment: @Sorack As the certificate of `cidadao.sinesp.gov.br` is invalid now, I failed to execute your program on Node.js `v10.15.x`. The error code is `ECONNRESET`.

Comment: That's because the service is only avaible for brasilian ips. I forgot that detail. You need to use a proxy if the access is from another country

Comment: @Sorack I used a proxy to make the test again. The `--tls-min-v1.0` solution works well. Please check the screenshot in my answer.

Comment: for me... --tls-min-v1.0 worked but a for a co-worker it did not. they could not connect to application. what finally worked was adding the max: --tls-max-v1.3... so we have min and max which gets rid of the error and allows everyone to connect. Not sure why!!

Comment: The `--tls-min-v1.0` flag needed to come **before the filename** (for me).

Comment: This is not working in Node version 17 onwards