# Proxy error: Could not proxy request react (EPROTO) nodejs 12.18.2

Tags: reactjs, proxy, create-react-app

I have a project created with create-react-app, and due to haven't local database, we're using proxy for server requests. So in my `package.json` file I have a line of code - `"proxy": "https://<remoteUrl>/"`. All was fine before I didn't update nodejs version. My current nodejs version - v12.18.2 and npm - 6.14.5. And I have an error "Proxy error: Could not proxy request react (EPROTO)", if I downgrade nodejs to the version 11.10.1 or below all is working. I've already tried the `http-proxy-middleware` npm package and got the same error message. I've seen couple questions similar for mine, but that solutions didn't help me, and the difference in my case that I need to use https remote url address as a proxy not another localhost.

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/56319636/1370487

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link, I've checked it, and it helps me to understand the real problem

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error

my line was

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:8800/api/"
```

it was fixed after changing it to

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:8800/"
```

even though its common in every path, maybe you're not allowed to to put it in the proxy.